# Define array length for c_char Python

Tags: python, c, compilation, header, ctypes

In C header file I have:

```
long param_API test(    
                        ___OUT_ char Text[41]
                      )
```

And after importing `ctypes` in Python code I am calling `test`:

```
out_char = (ctypes.c_char)()
def getRes():
    result = lib.test(out_char)
    return result
```

But I ma getting this error in the log files:

```
output parameter is NULL
```

I guess there is not enough space for test function to write thee output in. What am I doing wrong here? How can I set length for `out_char`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create arrays use:

```
out_char = (ctypes.c_char * 41)()
```

This creates an instance of an array object:

```
>>> (ctypes.c_char*41)()
<__main__.c_char_Array_41 object at 0x0000000002891048>
```

You can access the individual elements:

```
>>> out_char[0]
b'\x00'
>>> out_char[40]
b'\x00'
>>> out_char[41]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
```

And in the case of `c_char`, the whole buffer:

```
>>> out_char.raw
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Or just the nul-terminated portion:

```
>>> out_char.value
b''
```